# How to analyze ideal diode circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

For the first part of the problem, I have figured out that when Vs = 60 V, Vo is 50 V when D1 is reverse biased and D2 is forward biased.

The question also asks to find Vo when Vs = -60 V. This is where I struggle. I think D1 should be assumed to be forward biased, and D2 to be reverse biased, but I struggle to analyze the circuit; the -60 V is throwing me off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Why is D1 being forward biased, if Vs is -60?

Comment: In general, when analyzing diode circuits, you assume certain biasing for the diodes and solve based on it. If you encounter a contradiction, then your assumption isn't correct and you need to repeat the process with a different one.

Comment: Yes, the thing that's confusing me though is the contradictions themselves, like with the Vs = -60v, that means that the wires below have +60v. Im confused on how to go from there.

Comment: Just mark the voltages on each component with proper polarities (one convention is to use arrows) and make sure these conform KVL. The arrow over Vs will point downwards.